# Itertools ( groupby function ) with python 3.5

Tags: python

Im trying to figure what is going wrong with my code. Im trying to get right result but it's come out always random answer. Let's says for example I shuffle [ V, V, V, A, V ] I want the result to be [4, 1] but it comes out as [2, 1, 2]. Can you help me ?

```
class Combinaison:

    types_cartes = [
        Carte.AS, Carte.ROI, Carte.DAME, Carte.VALET, Carte.DIX, Carte.NEUF
    ]

    def __init__(self, des=None):
        self.nb_lancers = 1
        if des is None:
            self.des = self._lancer_des(5)
        else:
            self.des = des
    def determiner_type_combinaison_sans_as(self):

        valeurs = [len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(des)]
        valeurs.sort(reverse=True)

        sequence1 = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
        sequence2 = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]

        if valeurs == sequence1 or valeurs == sequence2:
            return " straight "

        elif valeurs[0] == 5:
            return " five of a kind "

        elif valeurs[0] == 4:
            return " four of a kind "

        elif valeurs[0] == 3:
            if valeurs[1] == 2:
                return " Fullhouse "
            else:
                return " three of a kind"

        elif valeurs[0] == 2:
            if valeurs[1] == 2:
                return " two pairs"
            else:
                return " one pair"

        else:
            return " nothing good, reshuffle"

class Carte(Enum):
    """Énumeration des types de cartes."""
    AS = 0
    ROI = 1
    DAME = 2
    VALET = 3
    DIX = 4
    NEUF = 5

    def __str__(self):
        if self == Carte.AS:
            return "A"
        if self == Carte.ROI:
            return "R"
        if self == Carte.DAME:
            return "D"
        if self == Carte.VALET:
            return "V"
        if self == Carte.DIX:
            return "X"
        if self == Carte.NEUF:
            return "9"
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort before you `groupby`. It splits an iterable by equality. It does not accumulate groups.

```
valeurs = [len(list(group)) for key, group in groupby(sorted(des))]
```

But it might be better to use the `collections.Counter`:

```
valeurs = Counter(des).values()
```